Preprocessing and model selection strategies
I am working on a fault detection problem where each sample is a time series labeled with a specific type of fault. I am using a CNN model and a validation set for hyperparameter tuning. Currently, I want to investigate the impact of different preprocessing techniques, such as using the raw signal versus applying a DFT.
To analyze this, I have the following matrix of validation accuracies:
$$
A=\begin{bmatrix}
 & \text{hprams}_1 & \text{hprams}_2 & \text{hprams}_3 \cdots & \text{hprams}_n\\
\text{Raw} & \text{acc}_{11} & \text{acc}_{12} & \text{acc}_{13} \ \ \ \ \ \cdots &\text{acc}_{1n}\\
\text{DFT} & \text{acc}_{21} & \text{acc}_{22} & \text{acc}_{23} \ \ \ \ \ \cdots &\text{acc}_{2n} \\
\end{bmatrix}, 
$$
where each $\text{hprams}_i$ represents a specific hyperparameter configuration, and each $\text{acc}_{ij}$ denotes the validation accuracy for a particular preprocessing method and hyperparameter setting. For example, $\text{hprams}_1 = (\text{number of layers}: 4, \text{learning rate}: 0.001)$ and $\text{acc}_{11} = 0.87$.
I have two questions:

My current approach for model selection is to choose the configuration with the highest validation accuracy, $\max(A)$, across all preprocessing methods and hyperparameter combinations, and then evaluate this model on the test set. Is this a correct approach?

To compare preprocessing techniques (e.g., Raw vs. DFT), I propose selecting the best hyperparameter configuration for each preprocessing method individually (i.e., taking the maximum accuracy in each row of $A$). Then, I would report the test performance of the two models corresponding to these best configurations. Is this a sensible approach?


In many papers I have reviewed, the methodology differs. Typically, data is split into training and test sets, and the learning rate and network architecture are fixed. The model is then trained on the training set using different preprocessing methods, and test accuracies are recorded over epochs. The maximum test accuracy and the final epoch accuracy are often reported. However, I believe this approach is flawed because it lacks proper model selection and may lead to biased results. Researchers might experiment with various configurations and implicitly choose the best-performing settings post hoc, which can invalidate the results.
Note: I understand that accuracy is not a proper scoring rule and also cross-validation would be preferable. However, for the purposes of this question, I want to work within the current setup.

I would say that your setup makes sense, and I would not know how to improve it (apart from the issues about accuracy which you seem to be aware of).

@StephanKolassa Thanks, yes I'm aware of that. So do you think that the methodology used in the papers is wrong?

It's often hard to say what someone did concretely, based only on what they wrote up, especially in the context of strict page limits. But yes, I do agree that analyzing methods on a test set very much risks overfitting to this specific test set, especially once people start running thousands of hyperparameter settings and discussing the winner without noting that some setting always wins, so the generalizability of such papers is often dubious.

@StephanKolassa Yes, indeed. If you'd like, you can turn your comments into a formal answer so I can accept it. I’d also be grateful if you could include any additional details or insights.

I did think about it, but "I think you are doing everything OK" sounds a little thin for an answer to me. Also, unanswered questions and especially questions without accepted answers have a better chance of collecting "real" answers. People have been known to differ from my opinion. And quite honestly, I don't have much else to suggest...

@StephanKolassa Okay, I understand.

A small improvement would be to not only select by highest accuracy, but also study the uncertainty of your accuracies. If one is 0.899 and one in 0.9 this difference might be pure coincidence, but maybe the model producing 0.899 accuracy is smaller (thus easier to train etc.)
